# How do I present alternate content for non-WebKit browsers when using webkit-image-set?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, webkit

I'm using webkit-image-set to make my images look all nice and pretty for users using a Retina Display.

Since this CSS selector doesn't work on an img tag, I have some HTML and CSS that looks like this (as exhibited in Apple's WWDC 2012 session):

```
<div id="iconImage">
</div>

div#iconImage {
width:152px;
height:152px;
background-image: -webkit-image-set(url(WebsiteIcon.png) 1x, url(WebsiteIcon@2x.png) 2x);
background-size: 152px 152px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Looks great on my Retina MacBook Pro! Of course, not when I'm using Firefox: it's just a blank spot, as I'd expect. I'm sure it doesn't show anything at all when viewed in IE either. Nor is it very accessible.

So, what can I add to the above code to make:

1. An image (probably the low resolution version) display in
2. Maybe some kind of text or alt text or
   something so that it's a bit more accessible to impaired visitors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do alt text for CSS backgrounds (not least because backgrounds should not be used for semantically meaningful images), but doing the fallback background is easy:

```
background-image: url(whatever);
background-image: -webkit-image-set(url(WebsiteIcon.png) 1x, url(WebsiteIcon@2x.png) 2x);
```

non-WebKit UAs will ignore the second declaration, while WebKit will ignore the first because the second overrides it.

Comment: Totally agree that I'm in a way doing the wrong thing here, but in a way since it's for an iPhone app and I'm an Apple fanboy anyway I don't care much. BUT - for accessibility - what about putting some text in the div that's the same color as my background (white)?

Comment: But won't that not validate since you're defining background-image twice?

Comment: @KobiTate There's nothing invalid about defining it twice.  Certainly not any more invalid than using -webkit stuff to start with

Comment: @bpapa If you set a background color (as opposed to background image) that contrasts with the text color, that would work...  Otherwise, I don't see how it would work in a browser that has image loading disabled for accessibility but is not using a text reader.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could create another class specifically made for non-webkit browsers.

```
div#iconImage.nonWebkit {
    background-image: url(WebsiteIconNonWebkit.png);
}
```

And then detect a non-Webkit browser using jQuery

```
if (!$.browser.webkit) {
    $('#iconImage').addClass('nonWebkit');
}
```

Comment: I just tested to make sure this works in Firefox using the following jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/acBLr/

Comment: Your CSS won't work with that JS... And more importantly, browser sniffing like this is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @KobiTate: You're adding the `.nonWebkit` class to `#iconImage`, so the CSS selector should be `div#iconImage.nonWebkit` (note the lack of a space).

Comment: @KobiTate As daGUY said, you had an extra space which completely changed the meaning of the selector.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky Didn't mean to put the space. Fixed.